# Apache rewrite rule to understand example.com to example.com?q=admin

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, drupal-7, url-rewriting

Can anyone help me out in getting the rewrite rule for the scenario as stated below.

When i type url "example.com" apache should use the same as example.com?q=admin. it should not redirect but inturn it should understand like this.

Comment: i meant when i type http://www.example.com/ apache should understand http://www.example.com/?q=admin. this http://www.example.com/?q=admin url should not exposed in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams says example.com is not a URL.

> From [IANA](http://www.iana.org/domains/example/)
>   Example Domains
>
> As described in RFC 2606, we maintain a number of domains such as EXAMPLE.COM and EXAMPLE.ORG for documentation purposes. These domains may be used as illustrative examples in documents without prior coordination with us. They are not available for registration.

I presume what you want to do is this.

`mydomain.com` to be redirected to `mydomain.com/?q=admin`.
Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^/$ /\?q=admin  [L, R=301]
```

To know the meaning of the flags used i.e. `L` & `R` visit: [rewrite flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags).

The number 301 means a permanent redirection.